Keeping the source of the MERGE statement materialized has failed repeatedly
While trying to run my DLT pipelines , I am repeatedly getting this issue

and not sure whats the cause here ?
Also I don't know how the merges happen with apply changes ?
Like based on sequenceCol and primary key if it matches it deletes the record or updates it? If somebody can point me right blog or documentation then that will be great !
Edit - using SCD-1 in the delta live table
